# proper rdp on Windows using raspberry pi

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, remote, windows, rdp

I trying to do RDP on raspberry pi 4. Am using one windows 10 pro as an server and three raspberry pi 4(4GB debian buster) as an client.Installed remmina on all raspberry pi system and grant RDP firewall access on Windows system.Am able to access windows system using one raspberry pi system using remmina.But i dont know how to connect all three raspberry pi to one windows system.Even after connecting one system to windows system, the windows system is getting locked and not able use that windows system also.
Is there any way to connect multiple raspberrry pi to one windows system?

Answer (score 1):

As per microsoft implementation you can take only one RDP session at a time. If you want to use more than one RDP session then you need to check the Terminal Service under Windows Server where it requires configuring an Windows Server with CAL license which will cost you too much.

There are other ways to achieve this using RDP Wrapper but by taking that route you will be violating the microsoft agreement.